# changing ownership of files within a bash script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, cron

I have this bash script which outputs the first two files as owned by user, and the next three as owned by root:

```
##################################################
# Variables
NUM="6"     #number of backup files to keep
LOGFILE="/home/boudiccas/cron/obnam-ls.txt"
####################################################

# Change into new directory
cd /home/boudiccas/cron/obnam/

# Generate new file and save it
sudo -u boudiccas obnam ls>"obnamhome-ls-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt"

sudo -u boudiccas obnam --config=/etc/obnam-back4.conf ls>"obnamback4-ls-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt"

obnam --config=/etc/obnametc.conf ls>"obnametc-ls-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt"

obnam --config=/etc/obnamusr.conf ls>"obnamusr-ls-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt"

obnam --config=/etc/obnamvar.conf ls>"obnamvar-ls-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt"

# Delete old backups!
find /home/boudiccas/cron/obnam -type f -mtime +$NUM -name 'obnamhome-ls-*.txt' -exec rm -v {} + >>$LOGFILE 2>&1

find /home/boudiccas/cron/obnam -type f -mtime +$NUM -name 'obnamback4-ls-*.txt' -exec rm -v {} + >>$LOGFILE 2>&1

find /home/boudiccas/cron/obnam -type f -mtime +$NUM -name 'obnametc-ls-*.txt' -exec rm -v {} + >>$LOGFILE 2>&1

find /home/boudiccas/cron/obnam -type f -mtime +$NUM -name 'obnamusr-ls-*.txt' -exec rm -v {} + >>$LOGFILE 2>&1

find /home/boudiccas/cron/obnam -type f -mtime +$NUM -name 'obnamvar-ls-*.txt' -exec rm -v {} + >>$LOGFILE 2>&1
########################################################################
```

How can i get the last three files to be owned by user through the script please?

Answer (score 4):

To change ownership of a file, you can use `chown`, this way :

```
chown newuser myfile
```

or, if you want to change group as well :

```
chown newuser:newgroup myfile
```

In your case, you can also change your 3 last lines to add `sudo -u boudiccas` before `obnam ...`, it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I know about chowning, but I'm really looking for something that can go in the script and be done automatically.

Comment: @user205787 and what is preventing from adding some `chown` commands in your script ?

Comment: You were right Levans, chowning did all that I wanted, nice and simply and easily. Thanks.